# Evaluate the integral by changing to spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

$$\int_{0}^{6}  \int_0^{\sqrt{36-x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^\sqrt{72-x^2-y^2} xy~ dzdydx $$

I tried converting it and I ended up with
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{72}}\left[p\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)p\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)\right] p\sin^2(\phi)~ dpd\phi d\theta$$

I feel like I could be way off here. Did I get anything wrong here?

(Apologize for the formatting!)

Comment: How do I format integrals?

Comment: \int_{a}^{b} xdx

Comment: hey @Chris, I edited your post to format it with mathjax, please take a look if I screwed anything up. The [] brackets seem to be redundant. Also, here's a good explanation of how the formatting works: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Notice that you are integrating above a cone: $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and below a sphere: $z=\sqrt{72-x^2-y^2}$. This is an "ice cream cone" shaped region. The outer bounds yield a quarter circle. Your bounds for $\phi$ and $\theta$ aren't correct. The cone gives you an upper bound for $\phi$ and $\theta$ only goes a quarter turn.

Comment: Evaluating the trivial $z$-integral first and then changing to spherical coordiates in 2D (i.e polar-coordinates) makes it easier imo. You then end up with two fairly simply integrals: $\int_0^6\left(\sqrt{72-r^2} - r\right)r\,{\rm d}r\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\cos\theta\,{\rm d}\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Intersect $z=\sqrt{72-x^2-y^2}$ and $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and get $72-x^2-y^2=x^2+y^2$ and so $2x^2+2y^2=72$ and so $x^2+y^2=36$. Thus the upper-hemisphere and cone intersect along a circle of radius 6.

Next, the outer bounds give: $0 \leq x \leq 6$ and $0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{36-x^2}$. This is a quarter of the disk $x^2+y^2 \leq 36$.

So your region is a quarter of an ice cream cone. :)

Your bounds for $\rho$ are fine: Take a ray emanating from the origin and you first hit the upper-hemisphere (of radius $\sqrt{72}$). So $0 \leq \rho \leq \sqrt{72}$.

Since you only have a quarter of the disk (in the first quadrant), $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

Finally, $\phi$ sweeps out from the $z$-axis. It stops when you hit the cone. The cone: $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in spherical coordinates is $\rho \cos(\phi) = \rho \sin(\phi)$ so that $\tan(\phi)=1$ and so $\phi=\pi/4$. Thus $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

$z= \sqrt{72- x^2- y^2}$ is the hemisphere above the xy-plane with center at (0, 0, 0) and radius $6\sqrt{2}$ while $z= \sqrt{1- x^2- y^2}$ is the hemisphere with center at (0, 0, 0) and radius 1.  Just on the basis of that, I would say that the $\rho$ limits would be from 1 to $6\sqrt{2}$ (or some subset of that depending on the other integrals) and the $\phi$ limits 0 to $\pi/2$.